# avrdude OS error: file not readable invalid argument

Tags: microcontroller, programming, avrdude, attiny85, usbasp

I decided to get into the world of "naked" microcontrollers (started with Arduino), found an ATtiny 85 among my parts and an USBasp and decided to first make a blink sketch.

Did everything like in these tutorials here:
https://www.instructables.com/Programming-Microcontrollers-With-a-USBasp-Program/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KkpYb1i1ZY
https://controllerstech.com/getting-started-with-avr-attiny85/

When I try to upload the program, I get the following error message in Microchip studio:
[image]

Has anyone got an idea what the problem is?
I already double checked my connections between the USBasp and the ATtiny85 and they are correct.

Edit: I installed the newest version of avrdude, now I get this error message:

"avrdude OS error: file ”C:\Users******\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\blink\blink\Debug\blink.hex” is not readable: Invalid argument

avrdude error: cannot set sck period; please check for usbasp firmware update

avrdude error: program enable: target does not answer (0x01)

avrdude error: initialization failed, rc=-1
- double check the connections and try again
- use -B to set lower the bit clock frequency, e.g. -B 125kHz
- use -F to override this check"

Comment: See if file is there and if it is legible even in a text editor (it won't look like text but you should be able to "open" the file at least)

Comment: The file is there and I can open it with Microchip studio

Comment: I cannot repeat your error on my computer. On my computer is working like a charm. Which version of a AVRDUDE do you have? And have you built the program before you tried to program it?

Comment: If the file is there, you may next try to venture into the world of calling the avrdude from command line yourself...

Comment: @G36 : yes, I have built it an it does compile without any errors. I downloaded avrdude v7 like shown in the tutorial. As I said - I did EVERYTHING like in the tutorials which I referenced in the links above.

Comment: @Abel : doesn't work for me. Windows cmd prompt tells me it cannot find the command or it was spelled incorrectly. I'm getting more and more frustrated...
:(

Comment: Try to create a new project in Microchip studio in C:\ or D:\ without any additional subfolders.

Comment: Also in the tutorial, they are using this version avrdude-6.3-mingw32. And it looks as if the operating system (or antivirus) does not allow Avrdude to open the hex file.

Comment: You can find where the avrdude lives by searching for it. Where it is normally isn't added to your PATH environment variable by default.  For example rhe one with arduino ide used to be in its hardware\tools\avr\bin\ folder.  It's there on your system somewhere.

Comment: @G36: tried creating a new project in C:\ - doesn't work  same error

Comment: @Abel : I tried to use the avrdude.exe from the arduino - it cannot find the config file  copied it into the arduino folder - doesn't work either
Seems like I have to get an Atmel ICE and forget the USBasp

Comment: Now you have a -r error. So this time wrong connection or no lack of supply voltage.  Also, sometimes a reset of a programmer is needed, simply to reset the programmer all you need is to unplug it from USB and then reconnect it. Do you have this chinese USBasp programmer?

Comment: Find where it lives.  Command line `cd C:\  && dir /b /s avrdude.exe` should get you all the dudes in the C drive eventually.